# Fake Operator Overloading

Tags: typescript

JS/TS does automatic boxing and unboxing of `String`, `Number` and `Boolean` types, which allows to use a mix of literals and objects in the same expression, without explicit conversion, like:

`const a = "3" + new String("abc");`

I'm trying to implement something similar for `bigint` and `number` by providing a custom class `Long`:

```
class Long {
    public constructor(private value: bigint | number) { }

    public valueOf(): bigint {
        return BigInt(this.value);
    }
}

const long = new Long(123);
console.log(456n + long);
```

This works pretty well (and prints `579n`), but causes both, my linter and the TS compiler to show errors for the last expression. I can suppress them with comments like this:

```
// @ts-expect-error
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands
console.log(456n + long);
```

but that's not a good solution for entire apps.

Is there a way to tell that `Long` is to be treated as a `bigint` or anything else to avoid the errors?

**About Why Doing That:**

I'm working on a tool to convert [Java to Typescript](https://github.com/mike-lischke/java2typescript) and want to support as many of the Java semantics as possible. The type `Long` holds a `long` integer, which is 64 bit wide, which can only be represented in TS by using `bigint`. The main problem with that is that Java automatically unboxes `Long` just like `String` and I want to support this semantic as far as I can.

For @caTS: so this will never be normal TS code but always used as `java.lang.Long` and hence there will be no confusion.

Comment: No and you shouldn't do this since it's going to be very confusing for someone else.

Comment: You can certainly lie to the compiler that `Long` makes `bigint` instances, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzPD1N) maybe, but it's a bad idea because `Long` is observably *not* a `bigint`.  Anyway I'm happy to write up an answer explaining, if that addresses your question fully.  Otherwise, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please mention @jcalz in your comment to notify me.)

Comment: @jcalz that's a cool solution. Yes, please post that as an answer. Not only is `Long` then recognised as being a `bigint`, but you still can use it like a class -> perfect. Check my question update for an explanation why I use `Long`.

Comment: Note that a `bigint` in JS/TS is *not* 64 bits wide, it is arbitrarily wide. In particular, you would need to use the `BigInt.asIntN(64, x)` method to wrap the results of overflowing operations back into the range of a Java `long`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt/asIntN Besides this, it's not clear what you intend for `new Long(x)` to do differently than `BigInt(x)` already does; just like your class, `BigInt` can accept a `bigint` or a `number`, and its `valueOf` method returns a `bigint`.

Comment: Yeah, the update contains inaccurate information; `bigint` isn't 64 bits wide.  Could you [edit] the question to remove that?  And @kaya3 is absolutely correct here; without any evidence presented to the contrary, using `new Long(x)` is worse than `BigInt(x)`, the latter of which returns a genuine `bigint`.  Could you demonstrate how `new Long` is better than `BigInt`?  I will write up an answer, but it will contain a caveat that you probably should not be doing this.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me about the bigint data size. I have to take special care to ensure `Long` only uses 64 bit. But I wonder why I should prove that `Long`  is better than using `BigInt` directly. That's not part of my question. It doesn't matter what is better, but obviously I have to use `Long` because that's part of the Java API and hence all converted code will use that.

Comment: _"I'm working on a tool to convert Java to Typescript and want to support as many of the Java semantics as possible"_ - Java and TypeScript are so fundamentally different that I'll advise you now that your project cannot succeed. What you **should** be doing is compiling Java to WASM instead: https://teavm.org/

Comment: Amazing what's possible today! Thanks @Dai.

Comment: My intent here, in addition to answering the question, is to make sure the question is good for future readers.  The general approach where you lie to the compiler about the type of `Long` isn't great because it has possibly weird effects elsewhere in your TS code (anything that interacts with `typeof x` is probably going to do the wrong thing),  What you really want is [microsoft/TypeScript#2361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2361), but that hasn't been implemented.  ...

Comment: ... so when you do something that's not recommended, it helps to have a good reason.  In your case, on the one hand, the fact that you're writing a Java-to-TS converter means you can make sure nobody ever exposes the weirdness, since you won't produce `typeof long` in your output.  On the other hand, it makes it harder to imagine containing all the side effects of occasionally coercing `Long` to `bigint`  (e.g., if you add two `Long`s you'll get a `bigint`, not a `Long`, and so you can't manage to keep the 64-bit requirement.)  So I'm kind of more wary of this now that I've understood it.

Comment: Anyway, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, with a caveat about how TS can't *really* model what you're doing with `valueOf()`.

Comment: Yes, my current approach is all but perfect, but would help to keep the original Java code semantic in place and require only minimal changes for special cases. If you like to discuss this more you can also [open a discussion in my project](https://github.com/mike-lischke/java2typescript/discussions).

Comment: @Dai Not all transpilers aim for perfect equivalence of the behaviour of the code; for example, Transcrypt compiles from Python to JS but not perfectly, it is quite easy to write Python code which does something different to the JS it gets compiled to. The point of such transpilers is to allow developers to write in a more familiar language with convenient features for the task; having access to e.g. Python's tuples, operator overloading, list comprehensions and so on can be a good thing even if you aren't guaranteed the exact same behaviour after transpiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the problems @jcalz already mentioned there's a big issue with his solution: you cannot use any of the functionality of the `Long` class. For the compiler as well as ESLint `Long` is treated as the `bigint` primitive type due to that additional constructor assertion.

However, JS has a built-in primitive resolution approach, described on the [Symbol.toPrimitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) page. In my original approach I used one of the solutions (`valueOf`) to let JS automatically convert the `Long` class to the primitive `bigint` value, which preserves all the `Long` class functionality.

Unfortunately, using the `valueOf` or `Symbol.toPrimitive` still require an explicit step (invoking either numeric, string or primitive coercion), so it's only a semi-perfect solution. Here's the class using this approach:

```js
class Long {
    public constructor(private value: number) { 
    }

    public valueOf(): number {
        return this.value;
    }

    private [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint: string) {
        if (hint === "number") {
            return this.value;
        } else if (hint === "string") {
            return this.toString();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

const long = new Long(123);
console.log(456 + +long);
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyD2A7A5tA3gKGt6AHArgEYgCWw0wSEALgE77DXy0AUutJAbmNQKbTcQ%20XgC5oifAFtCvWgEp00LDgC%20GZdgLEyAsEN4B5AGYs5YidNnoNObLV7V8tRNGoALEhAB0g4QG4bNRt2Lh5%20AG0AZQBPaXgQLyYABQ5JEmouXgBdFg9EajEaDhQFTFtbEiNoXJJ86ABeRugAIgsZWmbSm3Kce0dnVw9vX14AnuwVaF4QCH5K6rzqBqbmotrkTutx8r6nF3dPRPhIunXTMfGg7d2BiRAQC4mMIMpEGmgQJFR68V4AdzgXxYAEYAEwAZjkAVeEHivC8n2QLAALABWABs0AA1NjPiU-EA)). Note the extra `+` in front of the `long` variable, which triggers the numeric coercion. As you can see I have not used `bigint` here, because that is treated in a different way. In the original code no numeric coercion was necessary to make it work (only error suppression). Using `Symbol.toPrimitive` with `bigint` does not work, however, even with numeric coercion. It's simply not implemented. A proposal to add that functionality was [refused years ago](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/154).

So, in summary, for `bigint` there's no solution to my question (and `bigint` wasn't a good choice anyway). But for all other classes which can be coerced to a primitive type (either string or number) the mentioned approach works well, if you accept the explicit coercion.

### Update

I played with the suggestions from @jcalz to use a separate intersection type for the `Long` class. Check this [new playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYGwhgzhAED6AyB7Adgc2gb2gem9ATgKbJgC2h0AlgC7SICutiAZtNQBYUDuYAngFDQh0AA70ARiErBoEamGrSChMABMUIXtACyAQQAasAGq74AVQCi0ALzQAjACYAzABYArMgDc-QcLGSlYBQ5fHpgakR8AAoRfEoANwUKRJB6QgAuaHFKVEpkWgAfaGR6UnFCfABKTGgAXx9hUQkpGRS0gHlmKMrM7Nz8zF9GoSJqenxkaAAhHIBJfKiOSggAOjbCSu9G%20qGmgJk5BSVmfERSIzBUwijKTJKyip62XhFCFmgkNEHh4VHxyeQhC4cE%20qBum12O0azEQiG6NSCyAgiBAhBWIEQYIARJxeFjqrUcHhyBxEKp%20DtEXIPih0LYELToJAmcgtMzAcCoutejk8oViqVylUbAA%20LK8gYAMhBtO8-CptAxX1sHJpaCijicEKVqBWMLhmyJ0BxhDx0B8CrYXEQNjVupOZwuVyiDghVJRaIxYOo1rWlzSbuCHvRmKiOugAGorYhA0jg16oqCVnpDCZzBZKvwgA) for details. While this works apparently, it still shows a number of typescript errors, which I would have to suppress. Essentially all static members raise a TS error.

Additionally, there are other problems with this solution, like the changed class name (which is no longer `LONG`) when using `constructor.name` (which I have to use for reflection emulation).

Comment: It seems like this answer isn't really addressing the question as asked, which is "Is there a way to tell that `Long` is to be treated as a `bigint` or anything else to avoid the errors?" And the question mentions that you care about having (at least?) 64 bits, so `number` wouldn't work for that.  If explicit coercion were on the table for the question, then you wouldn't need `[Symbol.toPrimitive]()` anyway, you'd just use `long.valueOf()`.  You're the arbiter of what is an answer since you asked the question, but I hope you'll edit this answer or the question or both so they match.

Comment: "Beside the problems @jcalz already mentioned there's a big issue with his solution: you cannot use any of the functionality of the Long class." <-- shouldn't this be a comment on my answer so that I'd see it and possibly modify?  The question doesn't mention this one way or the other, but if you want a `new Long(4)` to also have `Long` methods visible, [that is certainly possible](https://tsplay.dev/Nar3ym).  I'm happy to add that to my solution, although it would be nice if the question said something about that

Comment: I've now modified my answer to keep any methods added to `Long`, so you can at least remove the part of this answer that mentions that as a limitation.

Comment: Thanks for taking care @jcalz. Unfortunately, even with this intersection type many other problems stay. Check the new playground link in my question.

Comment: ... in my answer

Comment: The "test" with `console.log(456 + +long);` is misleading at best (due to coercion operator bypassing any further type checks, I suppose). Make `long` non-const and try `long += 456` and watch TS throw a fit.  (Drives me mad that I have to come up with workarounds for this.)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you want, whereby TypeScript allows you to use a custom class [that overrides the `Object.prototype.valueOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf#overriding_valueof_for_custom_objects) as if it were the primitive type returned by `valueOf()`, is unfortunately not part of the language.  There's a fairly longstanding open feature request for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#2361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2361), but it has not been implemented, and it doesn't look like it will be implemented anytime soon.

For now, that means, there are only workarounds.  One workaround you could use is to lie to the compiler that `Long` has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that returns a primitive instance.  That is, you want it to have the type `new (value: bigint | number) => bigint;` (or perhaps `new (value: bigint | number) => bigint & Long` so that you keep any extra methods or functionality added to `Long`).

Here's how you could do that:

```
// rename
class _Long { 
    public constructor(private value: bigint | number) { }

    public valueOf(): bigint {
        return BigInt(this.value);
    }
}

// assign and assert
const Long = _Long as 
    new (value: bigint | number) => bigint & _Long;
```

Here I've renamed your original `Long` constructor out of the way, because once you declare `class Long { }` the value `Long` gets a constructor type automatically, and you can't change that type.

Then I assign the renamed constructor to the desired variable named `Long`, and [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it is of the desired type, `new (value: bigint | number) => bigint & _Long` instead of the actual type, `new (value: bigint | number) => _Long`.

I need to use a type assertion because the compiler would complain about a plain assignment; it knows that `Long`'s instance type is not `bigint`.

---

Okay, so now we have a class constructor named `Long` that the compiler thinks produces `bigint` instances.  Let's test that:

```
const long = new Long(123);
// const long: bigint
console.log(456n + long); // okay, 579
```

Looks good.  I can call `new Long(123)` and the compiler thinks the result is a `bigint`.  It also lets me use mathematical operators like `+` without complaint, and the result is what you expect.

---

So that works about as well as I can imagine.  Still, I would generally not intentionally lying to the compiler, since such lies can trip you up later in weird ways. The type of `long` is observably *not* a `bigint`:

```
console.log(typeof long); // "object", not "bigint"
```

And so any operation that depends on `long` actually being a `bigint` could do funny things the compiler can't catch so you'll see unexpected runtime behavior:

```
const bigint1 = BigInt(4);
const bigint2 = BigInt(4);
console.log(bigint1 === bigint2); // true

const long1 = new Long(4);
const long2 = new Long(4);
console.log(long1 === long2); // false!

function copy<T extends {}>(x: T) {
    return (typeof x === "object") ? { ...x } : x
}

const bigint3 = copy(bigint1);
console.log(bigint3 + 1n) // 5

const long3 = copy(long1);
console.log(long3 + 1n) // "[object Object]1"
```

Now in the particular use case mentioned in the question, since all of the TypeScript code will be generated, you might be able to guarantee that you don't generate any code that trips over any of these stumbling blocks.  But even so, it's important to be aware of these things and take them into account when deciding whether you want to proceed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/MYGwhgzhAED6AyB7Adgc2gb2gem9ATgKbJgC2h0AlgC7SICutiAZtNQBYUDuYAngFDQh0AA70ARiErBowFBGr56waonwAKEfkoA3MNQp6Q9QgC5o4yqkrJaAH2jJ6pcYXwBKTNAC+-QcLFJaWgjEwB5ZnV3c0trW0x-YWEianp8ZGgAISsASVt1DkoIADpQwncAbkSffl9+OWQFaCQ0aABeOBb0SGrkQi5odTKYqxt7R2dXD3aAPgtR+IAyTpRUCpw8AB4AWm3oMAATA-3kXmbV7YgRQmBKZmDmemQVShQwKWoBevlaEFX2xz9c5odQARgATABmSr8XCyH7QP5oEZxajfRqIECEYp-VDqAAsAFYAGwZADUiNWlQ2dAA1nwADTQQkAdgAnH4GhBMdjcQVeNcWJS0NS4QAiRDiABWN2oYqZyEQtDFsTGYs5CNVtlBAOyqDy1AJMK5tC11HButy+XxxvkPJxiDxZp1bVd81R4NFeEUJgAhBrGr9Vi7AQMukaqibhagLR0+mHVhH0dysQ68UjUC63RnPes4cx3hBCP7+I9ntRXhk5CJeJsACrQQgADwMyAOMAw3hm6ib5jrngw1RSaQy-MFrCb7TdEulsrFngA-F5iivJ95oOYm7UA00zZCAdXeOpnbaMam+XvoBTQchPHDCTug2h9x1D+oM6DTyneY736t99et40mKADakoyio0BhLOKgALqgmK0CAHwbgBUu34-BAA)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! However, for me the comparisons of the bigints vs longs is as I would expect it. The strict comparison is a reference comparison for objects, so of course the result is false for `Long`. The surprising thing IMO is that the two `BigInt` objects compare to true. But for my use case that's all fine.

Comment: They’re `bigint` primitives, not `BigInt` wrapper objects.  TS doesn’t let you use arithmetic operators on wrapper objects (presumably ms/TS#2361 would enable that too).  So if `Long` instances are supposedly `bigint`s then it should be surprising that they are compared by object reference.